# Getting a 404 for resource.axd on one server, not the other

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-status-code-404

I’m getting HTTP 404 when I access this url from one of the web servers, but works fine on the other. The deployed code is exactly the same on both servers because it’s deployed using CICD. The web.config is identical between both servers as well. I compared the IIS configs between the two servers, they are same. It should be something on the server that I’m not able to figure out. Vendor says it’s not an application issue because it works elsewhere and something on the server needs to be fixed.

https://serverIP/AppName/Resource.axd?r=DS.Web.UI.WebControls.Callout.js&h=20E547C24AB98AD419C9CC78656FC871

Stack: IIS, ASP.NET, Windows Server 2016
Note: Server IP and App Name is obscured in the url mentioned above.

Comment: Enable FRT and learn more about such errors, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis Since you have multiple machines, you can compare the trace log files from them and see what's the difference.

Comment: Thanks! FRT was new to me. I went through the documentation and configured the IIS. Looking at the report, there were no errors. Further researching into the issue, it turns out the app requires sticky sessions. Works well when there is one server but we see the error when two servers are in play.

Comment: Then how did you distribute traffic onto the servers? Load balancers usually support sticky sessions, and you can find the tips in their documentation or consult the vendors.